# Check name of list key and change it

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to check the name of a key in a list and then change the name if it meets a certain criteria.

My code so far is:

```
String convert(double key) {
  if(key == '1') {
    return "One";
  } else if(key == '2') {
    return "Two";
}


//This the the list loop:
for (var entry in optoins.entries) {
        entry.key = convert(entry.key); //This seems to be incorrect
        if (entry.key == "One") {
            //do somehting
        }
}
```

The error I get is this one:
`The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.`

I know I can do `if (entry.key == "1")` but later in the code I need `entry.key` to be a string `One` and not `1`, so I would like to change the name before starting the `if else` check.

Comment: The entry.key variable is a double and not a string. You are trying to assign a value of string to a double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your code entry.key is a double variable and not a string. I would suggest adding a new field to the entry class called stringKey and store this value there. That would be something like

```
String convert(String key) {
  if(key == '1') {
    return "One";
  } else if(key == '2') {
    return "Two";
}


//This the the list loop:
for (var entry in optoins.entries) {
        entry.stringKey= convert(str(entry.key)); //This seems to be incorrect
        if (entry.stringKey== "One") {
            //do somehting
        }
}
```